# Supabase automatically rearranging table rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have a supabase table with a column of boolean type, whenever I change the value to TRUE or FALSE, the rows get rearranged automatically putting rows with set to TRUE at the top.

I want rows to be in the same order as they were.

Comment: table row order is inconsequential, your query should specify the expected sort order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Postgres does not have any specific order at which they return the rows. You can sort your table by a certain column by clicking on the `Sort` button and specifying the column.

[image: Supabase dashboard]

If you want to sort the data that you query from your front end app, you have to add `order()` clause to sort your result:

```js
const {data, error} = await supabase
  .from('posts')
  .select()
  .order('created_at')
```

Comment: @Ketan Yeah, the dashboard sorting that I showed is just for the dashboard. If you want your data queried from the frontend to be in a certain order, you have to add `order()` on your query to order your results. I have edited the answer to include a simple sample.